# Delete in NSFetchedResultsController does not persist until after restart

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Even though I have worked with `NSFetchedResultsController` dozens of times, I have run into a problem I can't seem to find the cause of.

I have a `UIViewController` with a `NSFetchedResultsController` that manages the data source of a table view. Whenever I delete an object in the `NSFetchedResultsController`, the table view is updates by the fetched results controller, but when I save the `NSManagedObjectContext` (to commit the delete), an insert is triggered for the object that was just deleted. The net result is that the object is not removed from the table view.

The odd thing is that when the application is restarted, the object that was supposed to be deleted is actually deleted from the store and doesn't show up in the table view.

To be clear, I use only one managed object context, which is only accessed on the main thread. In other words, the setup is quite simple.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Fetch Store
        CCDStore *store = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Delete Store
        [self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext deleteObject:store];

        // Save Changes
        NSError *error = nil;
        [self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext save:&error];

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ with user info %@.", error, error.userInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Even though the deleted object is inserted in the fetched results controller, the object is turned into a fault, but I don't understand why it is added to the fetched results controller in the first place.

No exceptions or errors are thrown. I have performed several checks such as calling `isDeleted` and `validateForDelete` on the object to find the cause, but I have not become any wiser.

EDIT:

I am pretty sure that the fetched results controller's delegate methods are not the culprit, but for completeness I have added the implementation of `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    [self updateView];

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: {
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete: {
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {
            [self configureCell:(CCDStoreCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove: {
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume your view controller is the FRC delegate and that the FRC doesn't have a cache?

Comment: The view controller is indeed the delegate of the fetched results controller. I have tried both scenarios, with and without a cache.

Comment: I wonder about the "insert being triggered". Can you provide more details?

Comment: May we see your `controller:didChangeObject:`?

Comment: are you using a child context for the insertion?

Comment: After saving just perform a new fetch and reload data. You could also take advantage of `NSFetchResultsControllerDelegate` for this.

Comment: @MartinR I found this out by adding a log statement to the `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` delegate method. @matt I have updated the question to include `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`. @DanShelly I only use one managed object context with no child contexts. @flexaddicted That is an option, but not an elegant one in my opinion. Moreover, I want to find out why this is happening.

Comment: @BartJacobs: What does `[self updateView]` do? Have you also implemented the other FRC delegate functions like controllerWillChangeContent and controllerDidChangeContent? - Can you set a breakpoint at the NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert case and show the stack backtrace when that "spurious insert" happens?

Comment: Is there any specialised 'insert'/'delete' code implemented for the `CCDStore` object or an undo manager that is assigned to the main context?

Comment: No. There's also no undo manager assigned to the managed object context.